# earthengine upload table does not seem to be working

Tags: google-earth-engine

Back in October, I wrote a script to do a daily task...TLDR --> it modifies a shapefile, moves it to google cloud storage and then copies from bucket to an asset, so that the shapefile can be pulled into a GEE app that I wrote. It worked great for awhile. Now, the script runs, and throws no errors, and the updated shapefile correctly gets placed in my bucket. However, the copy to asset is not working. The file in my assets is a month of two 'old' (no updates). My bash script contains the following:

```bash
source /nfs/attic/dfh/miniconda/bin/activate ee

earthengine upload table --asset_id=users/dfh/ms_shapefiles/csodata gs://cso_test/shapefiles/csodata.shp

conda deactivate
```

When this runs, I will get something like this:

Started upload task with ID: 6MFSAZLDJ3KRRWPV6SRJLGYA

But then, when I check my assets, no update. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

It threw an error, you just didn't see it.
You would see this if you looked at the task status.

> Cannot overwrite asset 'projects/.../csodata'

You cannot overwrite existing assets.  You will need to remove the previous version before you can upload a new one to the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CLI, I found that the --force -f option actually would overwrite the asset correctly.